# Need to close iframe on click of cancel and print button in printpreview dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am opening an iframe on click of print button and need to close that iframe on click of cancel or print button. On click of cancel or print button iframe getting disappear but still I can see the same iframe in DOM so need to remove the same.

Is there any callback event like onclick on print or cancel button in printpreview in javascript???

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "opening/closing" an iframe ?

- **You can either show/hide an iframe on click event**

**HTML**

```
<h1>click me to show/hide the iframe</h1>
<button onclick="showHide()"> Click-2</button>
<iframe id="myframe" style="display:none" src="home.html"></iframe>
```

**javascript**

```
function showHide()
 {
   $("#myframe").toggle();
 }
```

or

- **You can open a new window and attach window.close() event on particular action.**

**HTML**

```
<h1>click me to open a new window</h1>
<button onclick="openWindow()"> Click-1</button>
```

**javascript**

```
function openWindow()
{
  var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
  myWindow.document.write(" <h5>click me to clsoe this window</h5>");  
  myWindow.document.write("<button onclick='window.close()'>close</button>");  
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PP7hxvZrgb6KBG9ybkfl?p=preview)

Cheers!